# How to correct onepage checkout in magento?

Tags: php, magento, checkout, onpageloadstring

I have one page checkout in magento for a [site](http://mysitetest.com.au/wardrobechoice/checkout/onepage/) and while choosing and option "Ship to this address" it remains on same tab rather than moving to the shipping method tab. How do I solve this problem, is this error occurred in java script or in code? Can anyone help me?
Here is the details in which i have edited for onepage for adding services in the onepage checkout:

```
i Have edited the /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml as
        <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                 <label for="servicepack">Services:</label>
                     <div class="input-box">
                     <input type="radio" value="3" name="sevicepack" style="width:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Priority Service</input><br /><input type="radio" value="4" name="sevicepack" style="width:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Road Express Service</input>

                    </div>
                    </li>
addedd this field and also   edited  /app/design/frontend/default/theme495/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
       <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                 <label for="servicepack">Services:</label>
                     <div class="input-box">
                     <input type="radio" value="3" name="sevicepack" style="width:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Priority Service</input><br /><input type="radio" value="4" name="sevicepack" style="width:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Road Express Service</input>
                    </div>
                    </li>
```

Comment: You added the services tab there ....do one thing please comment that out and check ...if it will working fine then we will proceed further

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow - this question does not show what you have tried nor what you actual problem is with out visiting the link, Please include a short code example that correctly mimics your problem with your question to maximise the probability of getting a great answer from the experts at Stackoverflow ? Perhaps you should read our ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide to learn how to improve your question?

Comment: @ Vishal Sharma  i just commented it but its not working..

Comment: @ karl-henrik  i added more details in it ..if u need more details please let me know..

Comment: Have u enable any shipping method in backend.

Comment: @SKP Yes I have enabled the tablerate shipping method ath the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If your running on magento 1.8

try this.

go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/ file payment.phtml 
open it, line 36

```
<fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

add id to fieldset

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```